# How draw route on Bing map from json response

Tags: asp.net, json, routes, response, bing-maps

I'm totally novice for Rest  Api, so i'm looking for example code. I've a set of geographical coordinates taken from a database and I need to find best route among these. I'm using Bing Maps, let say I have an idea how to code the Rest request, my problem is how parse and manage the JSON response to draw the route on the map in a asp.net page.

Comment: Hello there! I think as it stands, this question will be quite difficult to answer as it isn't really specific. I think you would be better off breaking your problem into small pieces, and trying to solve each. Asking for someone to write a fully qualified example app to do this for you likely won't go over well.

Comment: Hi rob, I'm not asking for someone write code for me, but  just an example how generally manage a json results and draw on map. Also something more o less similar.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using the Bing V8 HTML control, the directions module will handle making the REST request and displaying the result for you - there's no need to parse the REST response directly yourself. See https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk/directionscreatedrivingroute

If you're using one of the other controls, similar modules are available.

Comment: Hy duncan-lawler, the link you have posted was the first I've seen when begin to read the documentation. Of sure it is easy to read and to apply, but as you can see there are only two static waypoint, I'm in a situation where waypoints I must route (I know of the limit to 25 for non enterprise account) are dynamics, so I've put the coordinates into in array and try to add them dynamically , but seems that  in this way the route is not calculate among all the waypoint, but at couple of them: 2 waypoint  set a route, next 2 another an so on. So I've thinked that Rest request was the solution .

Comment: You can easily add/remove waypoints using the module - see https://www.bing.com/api/maps/sdkrelease/mapcontrol/isdk/directionsaddwaypoint

Answer (score 0):

I've found this [JSON](https://exceptionnotfound.net/geocoding-with-bing-maps-rest-services-in-net/), is a step to step guide to request and consume JSON response.